# Ensure that assignment does not copy an object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a variable `settings`, which is a list of dicts containing data for a few different things.

```py
settings = [{'name': "foo", 'data': 0},
            {'name': "bar", 'data': 1}, ... ]
```

Now let's say I want to modify the data for the thing named `"foo"`:

```py
[s for s in settings if s['name'] == "foo"][0]['data'] = 2
```

If I'm changing the contents of that setting a lot, though, that's a lot to type out each time.

What I'd like to be able to do is this:

```py
foo = [s for s in settings if s['name'] == "foo"][0]
foo['data'] = 3
foo['something_else'] = True
```

However, I'd need to be absolutely sure that this assignment is updating the dict in the original `settings`.

My understanding is that Python already does this. Is there any way that I can be certain that this is the case?

Comment: Assignments in Python do not copy objects. Test it out and see.

Comment: *However, I'd need to be absolutely sure that this assignment is updating the dict in the original settings.* - Well, did you run that code and something else happened?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would need to do it other than a single test so just print it

```
In [4]:     settings = [{'name': "foo", 'data': 0},
   ...:             {'name': "bar", 'data': 1}, ]
   ...:
   ...:     foo = [s for s in settings if s['name'] == "foo"][0]
   ...:     foo['data'] = 3
   ...:     print (f'{foo}')
{'name': 'foo', 'data': 3}

In [5]: foo['something_else'] = True
   ...: print(f'{foo}')
{'name': 'foo', 'data': 3, 'something_else': True}

In [6]: foo['data'] = 4

In [7]: print(f'{foo}')
{'name': 'foo', 'data': 4, 'something_else': True}
```